# Excel separate endings of words from root word

Tags: excel, string

Example of the text I'm working with in Excel.

```
Hablar
yo: hablo
tú: hablas
él/ella/Ud.: habla
nosotros: hablamos
vosotros: habláis
ellos/ellas/Uds.: hablan



=LEFT(Text,4)
=Habl
=Habl
...
```

This will take first four letters out easy enough, but if I want all but these first four letters I would have to use =Right(text,1) =Right(text,4) depending on the word.

Is there a way in which I could solve this with one or two functions?

Comment: See `Mid(Text, Start, Length)`, which you can use like `=Mid(Text, 4, Len(Text))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to strip the first four characters from the phrase, you can use the MID() function

=mid(A1,5,99)

In words, starting from the 5th character, return the following 99 characters. If there are fewer than 99 characters, all of them will be returned.